# How can a python object's classmethods be referred to inside the class attributes?

Tags: python

I would like to do something along the lines of...

```
class MyClassA(object):
    an_attr = AnotherClassB(do_something=MyClassA.hello)

    @classmethod
    def hello(cls):
        return "Hello"
```

however it will tell me MyClassA is not defined when I try to run it.

- `an_attr` must be a class attribute
- I can't alter `AnotherClassB`
- I would prefer if `hello()` remained a classmethod

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to get the order right, so it's defined before you use it:

```
class MyClassA(object):
    @classmethod
    def hello(cls):
        return "Hello"

    an_attr = AnotherClassB(do_something=hello)
```

Note that, because it's in the namespace when we're creating the class, we just refer to `hello`, not to `MyClassA.hello`.

**EDIT**: Sorry, this doesn't actually do what I thought it did. It creates the class without an error, but `AnotherClassB` only gets a reference to the unbound classmethod, which can't be called.

Comment: Excellent, I much prefer it being within the class definition.

Comment: This won't work as ecpected -- at least `AnotherClassB` can't do anything with `hello` since it does not know what class to pass as `cls` parameter, so this does not seem useful at all.

Comment: My bad. I'd assumed it was bound to the class by `classmethod`, but it seems to be bound by retrieving the attribute. Would it work for a static method?

Comment: The problem -- as pointed out in my answer -- is that the class does not exist yet while the class body is executed.  It would work with a `staticmethod`, but the OP stated he would prefer a `classmethod`.

Answer (score 3):

While defining a class, the class does not exist yet.  So you have to postpone the creation of `an_attr` until after the class definition:

```
class MyClassA(object):
    @classmethod
    def hello(cls):
        return "Hello"
MyClassA.an_attr = AnotherClassB(do_something=MyClassA.hello)
```

Comment: user387821 just beat you to it there +1 anyway.

Comment: @StephenPaulger: Well, I posted the answer first, as you can easily see by selecting the sort order "oldest" above.  Not that it would matter in any way... :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this will work, but try it out?

```
class MyClassA(object):
    @classmethod
    def hello(cls):
        return "Hello"

  MyClassA.an_attr = AnotherClassB(do_something=MyClassA.hello)
```

Comment: I was afraid the answer might be something like that :) Thanks, it works.